# How to build two versions of an application, using features, with a single `cargo build` command

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I need to build a CLI application that comes in two flavours. Most of the code is common to both, excepting some low-level layer.

So far, I've been able to specify the creation of multiple binaries using the `[[bin]]` notation, and using ad-hoc features. However, that requires to invoke `cargo build` twice, once with `--features="flavour1"` and once with `--features="flavour2"`.

- is there any way to have Cargo to build these two flavours with a single command?
- is this an anti-pattern? I appreciate features are additive, and it is recommended to avoid mutually exclusive features, but I couldn't find another way to do this.

To illustrate the question, here follows a sample `Cargo.toml` and the corresponding `src/main.rs` file:

`Cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "sample-flavours"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"


[features]
flavour1=[]
flavour2=[]

[[bin]]
name="bin-flavour1"
path="src/main.rs"
required-features=["flavour1"]

[[bin]]
name="bin-flavour2"
path="src/main.rs"
required-features=["flavour2"]
```

`src/main.rs`

```rust
#[cfg(feature="flavour1")]
fn sublayer() -> &'static str {
    "flavour 1"
}

#[cfg(feature="flavour2")]
fn sublayer() -> &'static str {
    "flavour 2"
} 

#[cfg(not(any(feature="flavour1",feature="flavour2")))]
compile_error!("Need a flavour");


fn main() {
    println!("{}", sublayer());
}
```

Comment: Use a [workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html) with two binary crates and a lib crate they share, and just `cargo b`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to have Cargo to build these two flavours with a single command?

No. Cargo can build multiple binaries in one command, but only with a common feature set.

If you find you need to run multiple build commands for your project, and want to automate this, you will need something external to invoke Cargo. I like the [`xtask` pattern](https://github.com/matklad/cargo-xtask), which lets you write your commands in Rust without any dependencies on additional command-line tools, but it may be overkill for your use case; a shell script might do.

> Is this an anti-pattern?

As you yourself noted, features should be additive. You haven't told us any detail about the code differences between `flavour1` and `flavour2`, but one possibility is that you can replace them with *generics* — perhaps `struct SomeImportantStruct<F>` is instantiated as `SomeImportantStruct<Flavour1>` and `SomeImportantStruct<Flavour2>` — or simply have two different structs/modules/functions/whatever.

If you can achieve that, then it will be *possible* to compile both of your binaries with a single command. Now, this does not necessarily solve *all* build problems; for example, it might be desirable to disable a feature for smaller code size or performance, or a feature might be actually impossible to compile on a given target. Or, unrelated to features, you might want to use a different [profile](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html) for the two builds. In any of those cases, you'll want to use a separate build command anyway.